# Microsoft Flow/Teams Adaptive Card

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, power-automate

Tried using the new adaptive cards feature in Teams that is supposedly live in Flow. Copied the JSON from the Adaptive Card builder online, replaced some strings with string responses from a Form hook. Don't see any reason why I would be seeing this error:

```
"error": {
  "code": "MissingOrInvalidBotAdaptiveCardRequest",
  "message": "The specified Teams flowbot adaptive card request is missing or invalid."
}
```

I have the flow bot enabled in the team and channel that I want the card to display in. I can't figure out what's gone wrong. Everything is entered as a string, right? It would be nice if they updated the documentation on both adaptive card posts and mentions in the Flow/Teams documentation. I'm happy to clarify, I just don't know what to include.

Comment: Could you add the adaptive card JSON?

Comment: too long. I've tried it with and without the "contentType": "application...card.adaptive","content": {" wrapped around it. Still get the same error

Comment: @DanielPadia - Could you please try posting your Adaptive card JSON using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio#card-editor)?

Comment: I copied the exact JSON provided from [the example in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card) and got the same error message.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is an example for using a Bot Framework bot with MS Teams. Have you tried a dead simple adaptive card through the Flow connector? Something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots#step-1-add-an-adaptive-card-attachment

Comment: Posted issue against the docs repo for Flow here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/flow-docs/issues/100

Comment: @AndrewClear I got the same issue with the JSON from the link you provided. Thanks for posting that in the Microsoft Docs github. I didn't know about that. Time to do more research!

Comment: Forgive me if this a simpleton answer.. But is that syntax correct? If you are creating an array of answers then does ERROR need to be in the quotations? Assuming you are using the MS Framework and that is basically typescript. Couldnt you just write in the vanilla JS? - Apologies again if that is a stupid question or point. Sometimes going back to basics (like finding a typo) fixes some issues. Thanks for at least entertaining the idea. Cheers folks.

Comment: @ZackeryGianotti no worries. And I'm right there with you. I know how easy it is to botch up syntax somewhere. The code you see the is json I'm getting back from a failed flow; an error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the permissions Flow needed in Teams. Once I resolved that and a syntax issue, everything worked out fine. Flow gives the same error whether you don't have permission or there's a syntax/schema problem in your post.